# What does "that" refer to in " This option reduces stitching artifacts that result when"?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I see a sentence in a book:

> This option reduces stitching artifacts **that result when** part of an
> object is rasterized while another part remains in vector form (as
> determined by the Raster/Vector slider). Selecting this option may
> result in extremely complex clipping paths, which take significant
> time to compute, and can cause errors when printing.

In the first sentence, it is difficult for me to understand the structure, especially of

> that result when

What does **that** refer to? Is it a subject or object and why?

Thanks.

Comment: The word ***that*** obviously references preceding ***stitching artifacts***. What else would you expect? It's just a syntax-required "glue" word, needed because of the verb form ***result***. It could be replaced by ***which***, or discarded completely if the verb form was changed to ***resulting***.

Comment: Consider what happens if you simplify the syntax with shorter sentences: *This option reduces stitching artifacts. Stitching artifacts result when...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers  *Stitching artifacts result when*? **result** should be followed by object, why can it be followed by *when*?

Comment: *Stitching artifacts result **when part of an object is rasterized...*** In this context, ***result*** means ***appear*** - and it's an intransitive usage, so there's no "object" - just the "adverb of time" ***when-*** clause.

Comment: oic - you missed the significance of the three dots after ***when*** in my rephrasing. That's ellipsis (there's more text after ***rasterized...*** in the last comment too, but it's not important for the point being made).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. May you tell me what is the meaning of the **oic**.

Comment: **Oh, I see!** (*Now* I understand! :)

Answer (score 1):

"That" is a subordinator and introduces the relative clause "result..."

In that relative clause "result" is the verb, and heads the clause. The subject of "result" is implied to be "artifacts". The verb "result" has no direct object, it is an intransitive verb in this context.  The phrase "when...." indicates the time or the condition for stitching artifacts to be produced.

The word "that" is not a subject, nor an object, but a word that indicates the start of a subordinate (and in this case, relative) clause.

Comment: Many people (the vast majority, I think) would say that a clause by definition requires a subject. You say *The subject of "result" is implied to be "artifacts".* Does that mean that "artifacts" actually is the subject? Or is something else? Or does the clause have no subject?

Comment: It has no *explicit* subject.  That is, there is no word that is in the subject position of the clause.  It has an *implicit* subject. This is the meaning that is understood to be the subject of that verb.  In languages other than English, it is very common for clauses, even main clauses, to have no explicit subject.  In English, the main, finite clause must have an explicit subject (and dummy subjects are introduced if required).  But relative clauses can have implied subjects. Non-finite clauses normally don't have explicit subjects.

Comment: Ah, OK, so "artifacts" is the implied subject. (That wasn't entirely clear to me from your answer.) I prefer to call the relative pronoun "that" the subject of the relative clause, but I now see how you're construing it.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer,  that is the "traditional grammar" analysis, but modern grammars treat "that" as a subordinator, not a pronoun.

Comment: I consider "that" a subordinator, too, but I don't consider that to be a distinct part of speech. But yes, there are certainly several ways of parsing such sentences!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan But subordinator **is** a part of speech (in trad grammar a 'subordinating conjunction'). In the OP's example, the subject is realised by an immediate gap: "stitching artifacts that ____ result when ...", where gap is anaphorically linked to the antecedent "stitching artifacts".

Comment: Interestingly, middle English didn't allow for such a gap, and required an interrogative pronoun.  Chaucer would have said "artifacts that which result"  (except he wouldn't have said "artifact" or "result" as these were not part of middle English vocabulary)

Comment: @BillJ Yup, that's another way of parsing it!